# How to ask spring to create corresponding schema for JdbcMetadataStore?

Tags: java, spring-integration, metadata, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-jdbc

I want to use jdbc metadata store which described here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-metadata-store

quote:

> The org.springframework.integration.jdbc package has Database schema
>   scripts for several RDMBS vendors. For example, the following listing
>   shows the H2 DDL for the metadata table:

```
CREATE TABLE INT_METADATA_STORE  (
    METADATA_KEY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    METADATA_VALUE VARCHAR(4000),
    REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    constraint INT_METADATA_STORE_PK primary key (METADATA_KEY, REGION)
);
```

I've found schema for my postgresql in the jar file. Sure I could just copy this schema and run in the pgAdmin once but I want to ask spring to check that my current schema  exist and if not - create corresponding schema from the jar file.

How can I cahieve it ?

### P.S.

Also in my project I use schema auto-generation based on beans(Entities) definitions so `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none` + copying schema from jar to local `shema.sql` is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is fully not related to Spring Integration JDBC support. That one is for JPA and is done really different way than `shema.sql`.

Actually those mentioned scripts in `org.springframework.integration.jdbc` package are auto-scanned by Spring Boot and an appropriate schema is populated in the data base.

See respective Spring Boot documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-integration

So, the option `spring.integration.jdbc.initialize-schema=always` should make your day and fully does not effect any other possible options.

Comment: It is really a great option