# JdbcMetadataStore: initialize schema, but for Spring app NOT using Boot

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-jdbc

Versions:

```
Spring: 5.2.16.RELEASE
Spring Integrations: 5.3.9.RELEASE
PostgreSQL: 13.x
```

I have implemented a pure Spring 5.x webapp; there is no Spring Boot.

I am using the `JdbcMetadataStore` and require that the PostgreSQL database be initialized with schema definitions located on the classpath in:

```
classpath:org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql
```

Following a [very useful article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59479319/how-to-ask-spring-to-create-corresponding-schema-for-jdbcmetadatastore) on the topic, here are properties I put in `spring.properties`:

```
spring.integration.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.integration.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql
```

This DOES NOT work.  After researching this issue, I have learned that the start-up initialization *is* supported, but in Spring Boot.

QUESTION:  Short of explicitly handling the execution of this SQL script elsewhere during webapp initialization, is there any standard way to load the script listed above at start-up?  NOTE: I am not using `schema.sql` scripts or similar to initialize my backend.

Answer (score 2):

See `DataSourceInitializer` in `spring-jdbc`:

```
/**
 * Used to {@linkplain #setDatabasePopulator set up} a database during
 * initialization and {@link #setDatabaseCleaner clean up} a database during
 * destruction.

 * @see DatabasePopulator
 */
public class DataSourceInitializer implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {
```

You need to inject over there a `ResourceDatabasePopulator` based on that script location:

```
/**
 * Populates, initializes, or cleans up a database using SQL scripts defined in
 * external resources.
 *
 * <ul>
 * <li>Call {@link #addScript} to add a single SQL script location.
 * <li>Call {@link #addScripts} to add multiple SQL script locations.
 * <li>Consult the setter methods in this class for further configuration options.
 * <li>Call {@link #populate} or {@link #execute} to initialize or clean up the
 * database using the configured scripts.
 * </ul>
 *

 * @see DatabasePopulatorUtils
 * @see ScriptUtils
 */
public class ResourceDatabasePopulator implements DatabasePopulator {
```

Some docs are here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-initializing-datasource

Comment: I decided to use the XML initialization (shown in your link, with `jdbc:initialize`). I copied the SQL script `org/springframework/integration/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql` to my project, and adjusted the table/index names accordingly. One likely initialization bug is this:  the `tablePrefix` property for `JdbcMetadataStore` can't be readily incorporated in `jdbc:initialize` (and quite possibly not in `ResourceDatabasePopulator` either).  So the native `schema-postgresql.sql` requires manual modification (ie, affixing the right prefix to tables/indexes).

Comment: That’s correct. Those scripts are samples how to start. You have to modify them manually